# date() with Unix time.

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm having trouble with filtering **strtotime('Monday this week', time()**

Beginning with the basics.
I use the following converter: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

I use to display the time: `date('d/m/Y h:i:s', $timestamp);`

```
1400630400 --- 20/05/2014 24:00 --- in php (21/05/2014 12:00:00)
1400544000 --- 20/05/2014 00:00 --- in php (20/05/2014 12:00:00)
```

Ok, displays time date +12 hours, but...

```
1400616000 --- 20/05/2014 20:00 --- in php **(20**/05/2014 08:00:00)
```

Why is this? Should not it be 21/05/2014 08:00:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `date('h');` only displays 0-12 hour format.

In other words, no real differentiation between AM and PM. If you want 24 hour date format, you want to use `date('H');`, 'H' gives you hours leading from 0 through to 24.

See the PHP Manual for more `date();` formats :)

**EDIT**

PHP date manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

1. it might be about timezones: https://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
2. as @Zander Rootman said, it's about format because 24:00 and 12:00 are the same hour, depending on format